# How to add folders to jstree with onselect ajax response from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree

**Due Diligence:** 12 hours

**Libraries/Plugins:** JQuery 2.0.3, JsTree 3.0.4, JQuery UI 1.11.1

**Problem (1 of many):** The below code block works.

```
$('.column-left').jstree({
        "plugins" : [ "wholerow" ],
        "core" : {
            "themes" : {
                "variant" : "large"
            },
            'data' : [{ 'id' : 'image', 'text' : 'image', 'parent' : '#'}, { 'id' : 'data', 'text' : 'data', 'parent' : 'image'}],
        }
    });
```

The below code block works as well.

```
$('.column-left').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=tool/filemanager/directory',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'directory=data',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {

            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

But what is exceedingly confusing is how to add folders to an existing jstree using the data received from server.

on.folder-is-clicked.ajax-call-made.children-folders-received.tree-folder-expanded-with-children-folders

Comment: wouldn't it be part of the success method?

Comment: I think that's a way indeed, but I just don't know the proper syntax for it. Docs lay out basic examples but not enough for me to draw from.